# Tensorflow Object Detection change output

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm coming up with this question because after reading docs and trying to find other posts where this topic is handled, I wasn't able to find an answer.

If, in any case, this is being answered somewhere, I'd be happy to just get a reference to the right place.

My Setup:
Anaconda Python 3.6,
Tensorflow 1.5
Webcam feed

Question:
I'm trying to find the correct piece of code or script which allow me to alter the output that the framework generates at detectiontime. In a standard setup, we get bounding boxes drawn around objects. That's great. But I would like to, for example, generate a file with the found object's data. Or even just print something out in the command line.

I don't know where to find the part responsible for this, I'm not a python programmer yet so I have no idea how to backtrace the code very well yet.
NOTE: I'm not asking for code just an indication to the part of the code responsible for the output :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are many ways of using object detection APIs. Are you doing something similar to this tutorial? https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/object_detection_tutorial.ipynb. Are you running evaluation job as in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/running_locally.md? You need to provide some details for how you are using it. I don't know what "standard setup" means.

Comment: Hello, thanks for taking the time. I'm using this guide: https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10. So it's just the standard TensorFlow 1.5 setup + the files provided by the GitHub repository. The written tutorial shows what files are added. I'm launching the Webcam Feed from the file https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10/blob/master/Object_detection_webcam.py

If you need more info or need me to be more explicit I will edit the post and add info : )

Comment: I haven't started editing the framework as constructed by following https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10 So I'm thinking maybe someone who knows Tensorflow a bit might deduct from https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-API-Tutorial-Train-Multiple-Objects-Windows-10/blob/master/Object_detection_webcam.py How to alter the output at detection-time. I'm searching for a starting point where I can create files when a detection is triggered and log towards the file what the framework is detecting